# NestJS: Set @Param and body values to DTO in POST request

Tags: api, parameters, request, nestjs, dto

I have a POST request entry where I specify an "account" parameter as a path parameter, and a boolean in the body to set validation state, like:

`POST /users/authorized/USER_ACCOUNT1`

The body would carry:

```
valid=1
```

I have the following controller entry:

```
@ApiTags('users')
    @ApiOperation( { summary: 'Set user account status.  '} )
    @Post('authorized/:account')
    async setAuthStatus(params: SetUserAuthDto) {
        return this.userService.setUserAuthDto(params);
    }
```

How I can feed both the "account" and the request body "status" parameter to the same DTO? I assume I cannot use both decorators @Param and @Body there.
Should I use pipes?

I'm new in NestJS so excuse my ignorance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using both `@Params()` and `@Body()`. It's a common pattern actually

```js
@Post('authorized/:account')
async setAuthStatus(@Param('account') accountValue: string, @Body() body: SetUserAuthDto) {
  // do your thing here
}
```

However, if you want to use a single decorator you could use the [`createParamDecorator`](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators) method and have it return `req.params` and `req.body` in a single, merged object, so you could do `@ParamAndBody()`

Comment: Thank you!  I'm still thinking where DTOs are useful and where they are a little excess.